# HTML 5 Boilerplate HTACCESS Stopping my mod_rewrite from working

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using HTML5 BP's [.htaccess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess) file unedited. Everything works fine until I add my own rewrite rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+-?[a-z]+)/$ /$1.php
```

this works fine if add it to it's own `.htaccess` file (after starting the engine and adding options) but does not when added to the html5 BP's file . I've tried placing it all over the document, inside the if tags, top of the doc and bottom.

The rewrite should load /example with /example.php , when using with h5bp I receive a 404 error .

Comment: "Not working" is not an error description at all. What do you have as input, what do you expect to see and what does actually happen?

Comment: try removing the `Options -MultiViews` line from the h5bp

Comment: Just a wild guess. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the line `Options -MultiViews` from the h5bp